# Need application that use FIPS 140-2 encryption libraries

Tags: email, encryption

I want send email in secure way. Do you have any recommendation?

Comment: FIPS 140 is a government standard, not a specific implementation. Do you "just" need to be able to send/receive encrypted mail?

Comment: Yes. I need to send my email secure way.

Answer (score 1):

Lockbin is a web application for sending private email messages and files. It's free! People use it to send things like credit card numbers or confidential information. 
Lockbin (lockbin.com) uses FIPS 140-2 encryption libraries, and takes extraordinary precautions to protect and destroy EPHI.

Comment: How does it work?